# Ignore parentheses with string tokenizer?

Tags: java, token, tokenize, stringtokenizer

I have an input that looks like: `(0 0 0)`
I would like to ignore the parenthesis and only add the numbers, in this case 0, to an arraylist.
I am using scanner to read from a file and this is what I have so far

```
    transitionInput = data.nextLine();
    st = new StringTokenizer(transitionInput,"()", true);
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        transition.add(st.nextToken(","));
    }
```

However, the output looks like this `[(0 0 0)]`
I would like to ignore the parentheses

Comment: could you give a few more input-examples? Is it just the first and last characters, then you could do `input = input.substring(1, input.length() - 1);`

Comment: what does comma (",") do in your token rule?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are first using `()` as delimiters, then switching to `,`, but you are switching before extracting the first token (the text between parentheses).

What you probably intended to do is this:

```
transitionInput = data.nextLine();
st = new StringTokenizer(transitionInput,"()", false);
if (st.hasMoreTokens())
{
    String chunk = st.nextToken();
    st = new StringTokenizer(chunk, ",");
    while (st.hasMoreTokens())
    {
        transition.add(st.nextToken());
    }
}
```

This code assumes that the expression always starts and ends with parentheses. If this is the case, you may as well remove them manually using `String.substring()`. Also, you may want to consider using [`String.split()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) to do the actual splitting:

```
String transitionInput = data.nextLine();
transitionInput = transitionInput.substring(1, transitionInput.length() - 1);
for (String s : transitionInput.split(","))
    transition.add(s);
```

Note that both examples assume that commas are used as separators, as in your sample code (although the text of your question says otherwise)

Answer (score 3):

How about

```
 for(String number: transitionInput
       .replace('(', ' ').replace(')', ' ').split("\\s+")){
    transition.add(number);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another variant

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class simple {


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  List transition = new ArrayList();
     String transitionInput="(0 0 0)";
     transition = Arrays.asList((transitionInput.substring(1,transitionInput.length()-1)).split("\\s+"));
     System.out.println(transition);
 }
}
```

**Output : [0, 0, 0]**

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;


public class simple {


 public static void main(String[] args)
 {

  List transition = new ArrayList();
     String transitionInput="(0 0 0)";
     transition = Arrays.asList((transitionInput.substring(1,transitionInput.length()-1)).split("\\s+"));
     System.out.println(transition);
 }
}
```